# Change the content of <a> inside <td> for every row in <table>

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a large table, each row has 6 columns. Each row looks like this with different value:

```
<tr>
<td>year</td>
<td><a href="2012/some_file_path.pdf" target="_blank">Some Title</a></td>
<td>subject</td>
<td>catego</td>
<td>Department</td>
<td>name</td>
</tr>
```

I want to use jQuery to replace the text in `<a>` ("some title" in this case) with its path:

```
<tr>
<td>year</td>
<td><a href="2012/some_file_path.pdf" target="_blank">2012/some_file_path.pdf</a></td>
<td>subject</td>
<td>catego</td>
<td>Department</td>
<td>name</td>
</tr>
```

It's like a debugger for me to verify if I have all the files.. but I have no idea how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

---

I have something like this in mind, but I don't really know the syntax:

```
function debug(){
    $('#datatable').find('tr').each
      $path = $('td:first-child + td > a').getHref();
      $('td:first-child + td > a').set($path);  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery objects have [an `each()` function](http://api.jquery.com/each/), which allows you to supply a function to be run once for each DOM element that matches the jQuery object’s selector.

Assuming this is the only table on the page, and the table doesn’t contain any links other than the ones you want to change, this should do it:

```
$('table td a').each(function(){
    // Within a function passed to each(), “this” refers to the DOM element for 
    // which the function is being run.
    $link = $(this);

    $link.text($link.attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Should be: `$link.text($link.attr('href'));`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: oh dear, you can tell I’m not writing much jQuery at the moment. Thank you; corrected.

Comment: Thank you Paul! and Rory. Now I start to get how loops and "this" work in jquery.Thanks! I wish I can code on the fly like you guys

Comment: @user893182: you’re very welcome. Be careful about the value of `this`, it’s a bit tricky in JavaScript. (Remember that jQuery is just a framework written in JavaScript, and not a separate language.)